# Create popover that can overpass window area

Tags: gtk3, glade

There is a small window application (50x50px) with only one image inside of it. When you click the image, a popover(GtkPopover) appears, but it cannot overpass the window borders and only part of it is shown.

How could I solve this issue without resizing the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Popovers in GTK under X11 cannot extend outside of the top-level window they belong to, because they do not use a separate windowing system surface; if they did, like menus, they would not be able to remain open even when clicking outside of them.

This cannot be fixed in GTK3, see:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747509
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/543

You must use Wayland, or you must ensure that your window is big enough to display your popover.

You also probably want to use [`gtk_popover_set_position()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPopover.html#gtk-popover-set-position), [`gtk_popover_set_pointing_to()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPopover.html#gtk-popover-set-pointing-to), or [`gtk_popover_set_constrain_to()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPopover.html#gtk-popover-set-constrain-to) to ensure that your popover always opens within the window surface, instead of outside.